# Regular Expression for not allowing pure numbers in python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

**Df:**

```
  String_Value
0 city
1 city233
2 123_city
3 123-
4 ab12cd
5 1234_
6 12/09/1998
7 @#987
8 189
9 123
10 @#+-
11 234-
12 Abc@
13 04-04-2004
```

**Output:**

```
  Bad_String_Value
8 189
9 123
```

I am looking for a regular expression which can solve this problem. In this problem i am not allowing pure numbers in my column, other than that everything is fine but not pure string. Column can contain anything but pure numbers.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: [A-Z|a-z] but it won't handle special characters

Comment: Have a try with: `^(?=.*\D).*$`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating what you should do with the regex(or might be very new to regex), instead of trying to match the cases where your lines are **not** only digits look for the ones where they **are** only digits. In this case you can use-

```
^\d+$
```

as your regex pattern. What this pattern does is -

- `^` establishes the start of a string
- `\d+` matches one or more digits repeating as many times as possible
- `$` matches the end of a string

Now you have all the lines which are only digits and you can then filter these lines out as you like.

Comment: I have tried this df.String_Value.str.contains(r'[^\d+]$') it's not giving desired results. Thanks

Comment: @kalyan Why did you add hard brackets ? That completely changed what the regex does. Your regex matches one non digit and the end of the string unlike the regex in my answer

Comment: @kalyan to make it more clear what your regex did was - [^\d+] looked for any one character that was not a digit or was not a + then the $ made it look for the end of the string, its not going to do what your trying to accomplish, on the other hand a simple ^\d+$ will.

Comment: Thanks @Karan Shishoo i got it.